# Can anyone explain this out of bounds array access in the MSVC++ std library?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, typeinfo

In the Visual Studio implementation of type_info, typically located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\typeinfo:

```
class type_info {
    /* ... */

    _CRTIMP_PURE bool __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator==(const type_info& _Rhs) const;

    /* ... */

private:
    void *_M_data;
    char _M_d_name[1];
    __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL type_info(const type_info& _Rhs);

   /* ... */

};
```

I noticed the implementation of the equality operator == uses the character pointer _M_d_name + 1. Can anyone explain to me how that "works", because it seems it would be out of the array bounds?

The implementation, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\ti_inst.cpp:

```
ASSERT_UNMANAGED_CODE_ATTRIBUTE
SECURITYSAFECRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
bool type_info::operator==(const type_info& rhs) const
{
        return (strcmp((rhs._M_d_name)+1, (_M_d_name)+1)?0:1);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically a way to write a variable-length struct.

Comment: Bear in mind that this forms part of "the implementation" which also includes the compiler etc., so they're free to do what they like, including making their uses of undefined behaviour... defined.

Comment: @T.C. thanks for your comment. Is there any chance you could elaborate a little?

Comment: @BenHymers Nothing can make this behaviour "defined" in terms of C++; it's just that within the context of the implementation they know what it'll do in practice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's his point already: it's sufficient that the behavior is defined in VC++. It doesn't _need_ to be defined in Standard C++

Comment: @MSalters: I know; I just wanted to make that absolutely clear for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick is for the flexible array member. It will allocate memory for `class type_info` and the name string, so `(rhs._M_d_name)+1` is exactly where the name string is. Here is a chart to describe it:

```
        +------------+ --+           
        |            |   |           
        +------------+               
        |            |   |           
        |            |    ->type_info
        +------------+   |           
+-------+  _M_d_name |   |           
|       +------------+ --+           
+------->            |               
        |            |               
        |            |               
        +------------+
```

Actually, c99 supports this feature and [a Microsoft extension allows the last member of a C or C++ structure or class to be a variable-sized array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fae073.aspx)